# calling methods dynamically with reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to call a method in an aspx.cs but getting an `InvalidOperationException` with message

> Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for
>   which ContainsGenericParameters is true.

My code is:

```
protected void BuildSurface(int newValue)
{
    IEnumerable<dynamic> models = InitializeConfigurationForWorkflow(newValue);
    List<Panel> panelList = new List<Panel>();

    foreach (dynamic workflowConfiguration in models)
    {
        Type dynamicType = workflowConfiguration.GetType();

        if (dynamicType.IsGenericType)
        {
            Type genericDynamicType = dynamicType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

            string methodName = null;
            if (genericDynamicType.In(typeof(List<>), typeof(IEnumerable<>), typeof(IList<>)))
                methodName = "GenerateListPanel";
            else if (genericDynamicType == typeof(Dictionary<,>))
                methodName = "GenerateDictionaryPanel";

            if (methodName.IsNullOrEmpty()) continue;

            Type[] listType = genericDynamicType.GetGenericArguments();
            MethodInfo method = typeof(_admin_WorkflowConfiguration)
                .GetMethods()
                .Where(w => w.Name.Equals(methodName))
                .First();

            MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(listType);
            panelList.Add(generic.Invoke(this, workflowConfiguration})); // here the error appears
        }
    }
}
```

my methods that will be called look like this one:

```
public Panel GenerateListPanel<T>(IEnumerable<T> workflowConfiguration)
{
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    return panel;
}
```

The dynamic-value is a json that gets deserialized to either Dictionary or List.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you want `Type[] listType = dynamicType.GetGenericArguments();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing an instance `workflowConfiguration` of a concrete generic type `dynamicType`, you need to use its concrete generic arguments in invoking a generic method that uses it as an argument.

Thus if your methods `GenerateListPanel` and `GenerateDictionaryPanel` have signatures like:

```
public Panel GenerateListPanel<T>(IEnumerable<T> workflowConfiguration)

public Panel GenerateDictionaryPanel<TKey, TValue>(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> workflowConfiguration)
```

You should do:

```
Type[] listType = dynamicType.GetGenericArguments();
```

I think you also need to cast the return of `generic.Invoke()` to a `Panel`.

Comment: you are a genius! :) Thanks man!
I also needed to change `workflowConfiguration` to `new object[] { workflowConfiguration }` when calling `Invoke`.

Answer (score 1):

There's another solution not involving calling method with reflection. Have a look at this:

```
if (dynamicType.IsGenericType)
            {
                var genericDynamicType = dynamicType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

                Func<Panel> generatePanelMethod = null;
                if (genericDynamicType.In(typeof (List<>), typeof (IEnumerable<>), typeof (IList<>)))
                    generatePanelMethod = () => this.GenerateListPanel(workflowConfiguration);
                else if (genericDynamicType == typeof(Dictionary<,>))
                    generatePanelMethod = () => this.GenerateDictionaryPanel(workflowConfiguration);

                if (generatePanelMethod == null) continue;

                panelList.Add(generatePanelMethod());
            }
```

Comment: Wow, that looks really nice! Thanks for this solution :) Here have my +1 :D